# Pass URL to menu item call back

Tags: routes

I'm implementing `hook_menu` to add a new tab to the user account page. I'd like to pass a URL as the page callback (a local URL for an existing page on the site). the `page_callback` parameters just accepts a function name. 
**How would I go about using that to pass a URL?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `page arguments`:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['foo'] = array(
    'title' => 'Bar',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_baz',
    'page arguments' => array('http://google.com', 'another arg'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_baz($url, $another_arg) {
  // Do something with $url, e.g. redirect.
  drupal_goto($url);
}
```

That's quite a contrived example, if you *are* redirecting, you could shorten that by just using `drupal_goto` as the callback:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['foo'] = array(
    'title' => 'Bar',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
    'page arguments' => array('http://google.com'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: The problem with that implementation is that drupal_goto completely redirects to the page. I want the page embedded in the user account tab.

Comment: That's pretty straightforward too, you just need to find out what page callback _that_ page is using, along with the arguments. Where does the page you want to embed come from? Custom code? Node? Something else maybe? I should point out I don't think Drupal has a mechanism to proxy another page by URL, so there'll be a small amount of code involved

Comment: @lcdservices I am agree with Clive, It is seems you don't have clear view about mechanism of menu routering in drupal

Comment: It's proving difficult to do that because the other module the page is generated from isn't loaded at the point this tab is called.